# About android layout with two imageView

Tags: android-layout

I have movies Application
and I am working in the details of the movie layout

now I have two posters for each movie (orginal poster and backdrop poster)

I am working to make some thing like this:

[image: THIS]

I am trying to do that but I have problem which is: the backdrop poster came to the front of orginal poster and hide it (backdrop poster hide the orginal poster)
how I can send the original poster to the front of backdrop poster

this is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_movie_poster1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_movie_poster_back"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        <!--android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_movie_poster1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_movie_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#57486c"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                tools:text="The Hunger Games" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_movie_lang"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                tools:text="English" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_movie_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="7.4/10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_movie_year"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                tools:text="2015"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_movie_overview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                tools:text="Katniss Everdeen and Peeta Mellark become targets of the Capitol after their victory in the 74th Hunger Games sparks a rebellion in the Districts of Panem. " />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made the *layout* i think it will fulfill your requirement. Using `Frame Layout` overlay the poster `image` on the back `image` and accordingly manage.

Follow this `XML` part for upper layer. Make changes accordingly relate to `images` you used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_movie_poster1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/testimage" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_movie_poster_back"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here you can view the upper layer output.

[image]

Comment: That's Awesome <3 Thank you very much